# mysql grant rights with wildcards

Tags: mysql

I have about 100 separate mysql databases and i would like to add user rights with wildcards. I read the doc with the foobar example but there is something I'm missing.
id like to grant permissions to all databases that start with server_x2.
I ran this query and it worked no problem.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `server_v2%`.`%` TO 'server_admin'@'%';
```

when i try to grant specific privileges to a another user, it errors with table does not exist.

```
GRANT SELECT ON `server_v2%`.`%` TO 'user1'@'%';
```

Any thoughts on where ive gone wrong. without backticks i get syntax error. i tried adding backslashes before the underscore. I tried just removing the underscores to make sure that wasn't messing up the wildcards.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MySQL GRANT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-database-privileges)

> The _ and % wildcards are permitted when specifying database names in
> GRANT statements that grant privileges at the database level (GRANT
> ... ON db_name.*). This means, for example, that to use a _ character
> as part of a database name, specify it using the \ escape character as
> _ in the GRANT statement, to prevent the user from being able to
> access additional databases matching the wildcard pattern (for
> example, GRANT ... ON `foo\_bar`.* TO ...).

Try:

```
grant all privileges on `server_v2\_%`.* to user1@`%`;
```

Tested:

```
mysql> select version();
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.7.34-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> create database server_v2_2014;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> create database server_v2_2015;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> create database server_v2_2016;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> create database server_v_2014;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> create user user1@`%` identified by 'MyPasswrod1234';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)


mysql> show grants for user1@`%`;
+-----------------------------------+
| Grants for user1@%                |
+-----------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user1'@'%' |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant all privileges on `server_v2\_%`.* to user1@`%`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> show grants for user1@`%`;
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user1@%                                      |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user1'@'%'                       |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `server_v2\_%`.* TO 'user1'@'%' |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------------+
| Database                 |
+--------------------------+
| information_schema       |
| mysql                    |
| performance_schema       |
| server_v2_2014           |
| server_v2_2015           |
| server_v2_2016           |
| server_v_2014            |
| sys                      |
+--------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then I logged from another server testing the user:

```
basha04:~ # mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u user1 -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 48
Server version: 5.7.34-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MySQL [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| server_v2_2014     |
| server_v2_2015     |
| server_v2_2016     |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MySQL [(none)]> select current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| user1@%        |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MySQL [(none)]> use server_v2_2016;
Database changed
MySQL [server_v2_2016]> create table t1 (id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.725 sec)

MySQL [server_v2_2016]> show create table t1;
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                           |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| t1    | CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MySQL [server_v2_2016]> use server_v2_2015;
Database changed
MySQL [server_v2_2015]> use server_v2_2016;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
MySQL [server_v2_2016]>
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much for help!